# LINQ to XML type declaration

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

If we're using *C# **([LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx))*** to loop through nodes contained in a small (< 100kb) ***[XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387063.aspx)*** object is it a better practice or better performance-wise to use ***[XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387085.aspx)*** or the standard implicit "***[var](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx)***" type?

Illustrated:

```
foreach (XElement el in node.Elements())
{
    ...
}
```

or

```
foreach (var el in node.Elements())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did you seriously expect that will have measurable impact on performance? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not change anything. `var` is just a short form for developers to write shorter code. While compiling it will be revamped back to `XElement` in your case.

`var` is strongly typed! Please do not understand `var` like a type free variable in PHP.

An example:

PHP

```
$i = 3;
$i = new MyObject();
//Everything is fine
```

C#

```
var i = 3;
i = new MyObject();
//compiler error!
```

So there is no difference between

```
var i = 3;
```

and

```
int i = 3;
```

After compiling `var` is anyways replaced by `int`, so there will be no better performance while execution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However I disagree with the statement that "it doesn't change anything" as the fact that the compiler has to do the job of reading the right side of the statement to appropriately define and supply the definition to the left opposed to me simply typing out for example `IEnumerable<XElement> query = from...`. I do agree (based on my experience) and the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) supports the  fact that the `var` in your example would in fact be typed by the compiler as `int`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference for performance, because type inference in .NET occurs on compile time. All variables will be strongly typed after compilation.

Also there is no rule for usage `var` or type name for variable declaration. It's a matter of personal preference. Some people like to see type of variable they working with, some people consider type declaration as form of duplication (not case for foreach statement, but for simple variable declaration).

Real power of `var` goes when you are working with anonymous types (that's why it was introduced). You simply can't specify type name of variable:

```
var people = from p in doc.Descendants("Person")
             select new { p.Name, p.Id };
```

Consider reading [Implicitly Typed Local Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) article.

Comment: Thanks! I did view that link however and it's sort of what lead me to ask the question here in the forums. I guess I'm now only curious as to just how much time (negligible I'm sure) is spent for the compiler to digest and infer the type when the right side is compiled to supply the 'type' definition for the left (var) of the statement opposed to simply typing IEnumerable<XElement> instead of "var." I completely agree and the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) supports that "var" fixes the anonymous types problem. Thanks again!

Comment: @id.ot I'm not sure why does compilation time matter to you, but why don't you try measuring it?

Comment: simply put... the task I've been working on is a test for employment so I'm just looking to do the best I can. I definitely can test/measure it, thanks again.